# Easiest way to split a change set in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I'm comfortable using git, but have been exploring Mercurial lately out of curiosity based on a friends opinion that it is better in some ways.

One of the first things I noticed however is that Mercurial does not appear to have an index as git does.  I tend to make more changes then I should sometimes and after editing the file I will use `git add -p` to split the patch into separate commits.  If the changes are in different files I could probably use MQ, but otherwise it looks like I need to undo changes first.

Is there maybe an extension for Mercurial that provides index-like functionality?

Comment: there is a `mercurial` tag, and `hg` auto-redirects to that.  Not sure what issue you hit.

Comment: Probably you have the "R" key missing in your keyboard. :-) I've corrected all your mecurial entries to mercurial. So, I think you've also searched for a tag named "mecurial"...

Comment: Thanks, i was creating this on my ipad while riding the train, so seems likely i fumbled a few keys here and there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're correct that there's no git-style index.  You can use [`hg record`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RecordExtension) (distributed with Mercurial) or [`hg crecord`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CrecordExtension).  Both let you choose on a per-file or per-hunk basis when committing.  `crecord` is a more sophisticated, but requires curses.

**UPDATE (2016-11-19)**

The functionality of the crecord extension now is available in core Mercurial. Also the usage is better integrated. The preferred way to commit selected hunks is

```
$ hg commit --interactive
```

By default this behaves like the old *record* command. To get the curses based interface like in the old *crecord* command, set this in your [HGRC](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui):

```
[ui]
interface = curses
```

Comment: I use the `crecord` extension very often, it makes selective commits a breeze.

Comment: Matthew, pardon the update edit for `commit --interactive`. Actually it was intended for another answer. Looking at it, it still makes sense. So I'll just leave it there. Feel free to remove it if you prefer your original answer.

Comment: If you know mq, mq also supports the curses interfaces with qcrecord and qcrefresh.  (It seems like mq is getting deprecated in favor of changeset evolution — where you'd use commit or crecord as mentioned earlier — but I don't know how quickly that deprecation is happening.)

Answer (score 49):

There are two ways to split a changeset, depending on whether or not you've already committed the changes that you wish to split:

To selectively commit changes from your working directory (if you haven't committed your changes yet):

- Use [`hg record`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RecordExtension).  (This is similar to using `git commit --patch`.)

To split an existing changeset (if you've already committed your changes):

1. Use [`hg histedit`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension) and select the *edit* option on the changeset you want to edit.
   (This is similar to using `git rebase -i`.)
2. Use `hg record` to selectively commit your changes as separate changesets.
3. Use `hg histedit --continue` when you're done.  The remaining uncommitted changes will be included in a final changeset.

As others have mentioned, you can use [`hg crecord`](https://bitbucket.org/edgimar/crecord/wiki/Home) in the place of `hg record`.

Comment: Using '[Mercurial evolve](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EvolveExtension)', it's now also possible to do 'hg uncommit' to extract parts of a commit back into the working directory. 'hg uncommit file/you/want/in/a/separate/commit', followed by 'hg commit -m newcommit' will nicely split up your commit.
Just keep in mind that 'Mercurial evolve' is, as of 2014, still experimental.

Comment: After finishing the 3 steps, I rebased the tip to the former parent. Following your steps with a history of `A -> B` you end up with `A -> C -> B'` whereas I was going for `B' <- A -> C`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested to read this article that explains how another mercurial extension, patch queues, are like git's index on steroids:

http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/08/a-git-users-guide-to-mercurial-queues/

Comment: To me MQ serves the same role as git rebase -i.  The index is just for selecting files and hunks to include in the commit.  If you want to manage a patch queue in git you simply create a branch and use commit rather than qrefresh.

Comment: The equivalent to `git rebase -i` is `hg histedit`, from the third-party histedit extension. Like in Git, you can just create a branch for your experimental work, possibly with a bookmark on it to better track it. Then use histedit to collapse and rearrange the changesets before merging back.

Comment: Mercurial Queues are very flexible and are super easy to use for both emulating git's index, **and** for giving you `git rebase -i` or `hg histedit` capability.  Read the article I linked to, if you haven't already, and play with the mq extension.  Patch queues sounded like a step backwards in revision control tools until I read that and tried them out.  They are a little bit mind-blowing.

Comment: I read the article, but my conclusion was that all of this can be done easily in git and the author is comparing hg apples to gits oranges.  Index != mq.  Git does have patch queues, but they are called branches. Git checkout -b newfeature;hack hack; git commit -a; oops qrefresh= git commit --amend; hack hack; git commit -a; hmm lets reorder them: git rebase -i master; hmm lets split that last commit too: git reset HEAD; git add -p; git commit; git commit -a; ok looks good lets peer review: git push origin newfeature lookatme; merge it: git checkout master; git merge newfeature.

Comment: Well, the original question was if mercurial had an extension that mimics git's index.  I submitted that mercurial queues are that extension.  You seemed to disagree by saying that mq was git rebase -i, not the index.  I still say mq can do either (and that's fine if git doesn't need mq, that wasn't the original question) and I hope I have helped the original poster find something that gives mercurial a git-like index.